# Pretty-print Java method signature and parse back

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm making a Java bytecode editor that translates bytecode to some sort of intermediate code that can be changed by user, then parse that code back to bytecode. For now, the method declaration looks terrible and hard to read. But, well, it works.

```
method [public,static] testMethod (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; throws [java/lang/Exception] <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(TT;)TT;
```

As you can see there is a access flags, method name, method description, generics signature and exception that I get from

```
org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor#visitMethod
```

Is there a convenient way to make it looks like in a original source code, and then extract from that pretty string all that information back?
The method above should be like this:

```
public static <T> T testMethod(T) throws Exception
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well, just write a parser. I think ANTLR has example grammars to get you started.

Comment: Well the first thing that comes to mind is to use a regular expression with the right capture groups. That should give you the right information in each group. But you know what they say... a programmer has a problem and decides to solve it with regular expressions. Now he has two problems! Alternatively you could just code a parser method to return you an object containing the fields you need. Getting the pretty output could be as simple (?) as using the toString to format it as you like... And yes I also like the ANTLR proposal by @Axel

Answer (score 2):

If you implement the [method](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))

```
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(
  int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions)
```

you already have most of the needed information which you can assemble to a human readable declaration. The biggest obstacle is the signature, but thankfully, the ASM library already provides tools helping on this purpose.

The following code uses [`SignatureReader`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureReader.html) and [`TraceSignatureVisitor`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceSignatureVisitor.html) to format them. Unfortunately, it requires a bit of post processing as it does not separate type parameters and method parameters and it omits `Object` return types for non-generic methods. Further, it generates an exception list only if there are generic exceptions, so we have to do it manually otherwise.

```java
static String decode(int access, String name, String desc,
                     String signature, String[] exceptions) {

    if(signature == null) signature = desc;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    appendModifiers(sb, access);
    TraceSignatureVisitor v = new TraceSignatureVisitor(0);
    new SignatureReader(signature).accept(v);

    String declaration = v.getDeclaration(), rType = v.getReturnType();
    if(declaration.charAt(0) == '<')
        sb.append(declaration, 0, declaration.indexOf("(")).append(' ');
    else if(rType.isEmpty() || rType.charAt(0) == '[')
        sb.append("java.lang.Object");
    sb.append(rType).append(' ').append(name)
      .append(declaration, declaration.indexOf('('), declaration.length());
    if((access & Opcodes.ACC_VARARGS) != 0 && declaration.endsWith("[])"))
        sb.replace(sb.length() - 3, sb.length(), "...)");
    String genericExceptions = v.getExceptions();
    if(genericExceptions != null && !v.getDeclaration().isEmpty())
        sb.append(" throws ").append(genericExceptions);
    else if(exceptions != null && exceptions.length > 0) {
        sb.append(" throws ");
        int pos = sb.length();
        for(String e:exceptions) sb.append(e).append(", ");
        int e = sb.length() - 2;
        sb.setLength(e);
        for(; pos < e; pos++) if(sb.charAt(pos) == '/') sb.setCharAt(pos, '.');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static void appendModifiers(StringBuilder buf, int access) {
    for(int bit; access != 0; access -= bit) {
        bit = access & -access;
        buf.append(switch(bit) {
            case Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC -> "public ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE -> "private ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_PROTECTED -> "protected ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_STATIC -> "static ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_FINAL -> "final ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_ABSTRACT -> "abstract ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_NATIVE -> "native ";
            case Opcodes.ACC_SYNCHRONIZED -> "synchronized ";
            default -> "";
        });
    }
}
```

<sup>The `appendModifiers` method has been adapted for recent Java versions, for old versions look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33039128/1)</sup>

It also decodes the modifiers manually, as you can see at the end, but that’s not such a big deal.

If you test it with:

```
String[] exceptions={"java/lang/Exception"};
System.out.println(decode(9, "testMethod",
    "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;",
    "<T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(TT;)TT;", exceptions));
```

it will print:

```
public static <T> T testMethod(T) throws java.lang.Exception
```

---

When it comes to parsing such a declaration, it gets more complicated. Since you are going to implement an *editor* rather than an assembler, you may think about the alternative of just providing distinct editors components for the different features, e.g. checkboxes and comboboxes for the modifiers, a textfield for the name and a list editor for the parameter types.

At this point, I’d recommend studying the [`Type`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/Type.html) class. It allows extracting the [parameter types](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getArgumentTypes(java.lang.String)) and [return type](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getReturnType(java.lang.String)) from a signature and after applying changes you may [recreate a signature](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getMethodDescriptor(org.objectweb.asm.Type,%20org.objectweb.asm.Type...)).

Similarly, [`SignatureReader`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureReader.html) and [`SignatureWriter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureWriter.html) may help dealing with generic signature in a structural way rather than converting them to textual form and reparsing this form back.